# Reputation gained from an accepted answer and an upvote.

Tags: support, reputation

Has there been a change in the reputation earned from receiving both an upvote and an accepted answer? It should be 15 + 10 points earned, yet [this accepted and upvoted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937700/the-vector-space-lx-y-of-linear-maps/937778#937778) only earned me 15 reputation points, propelling me from 8003 points to a measly 8018 points (although both Daniel R and Martin Sleziak's links suggest I earned 25 points).

Yes, I take this seriously ^^

**Update:** It's jumped to 8028, at least on my main user profile. I don't know what happened there.

Comment: I have checked reputation league [here](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/month/math/2014-09-01/11258#11258). I assume it is updated about once a day, so that number is (probably) from yesterday. And it shows 8003 points: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UHcUb.png

Comment: BTW you can have a look at your complete reputation breakdown here: http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/11258/olivier-b%C3%A9gassat?tab=reputation) tells a different story, you did get 25 points.

Comment: Yet my reputation is at 8018...

Comment: @MartinSleziak the reputation breakdown says my reputation is at 8028... Yet it is at 8018.

Comment: I have had a look at this post: [How do I audit my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation). Among other things it mentions that: *repuatation recalc is performed automatically*. But I do not know under what circumstances or how often it the recalc is started.

Comment: In one of the answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/how-often-is-reputation-recalculated) it is said that reputation recalc on an account can be triggerd by a ♦moderator.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I think that is outdated. I don't see a way to trigger a rep recalc on someone else's account.

Comment: Have you checked the "show removed posts" box on your profile? It could be that a question was deleted with an answer of you with one upvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "reputation recalc" was recently triggered on your account. (This used to be something users/mods could do, but that functionality was removed in Dec 2013.) The sequence of events was almost certainly as follows. The upvote given on your answer and the corresponding reputation change were stored in the central database but somehow did not immediately trigger a *visible* reputation increase on your account. Later an automated process detected a possible discrepancy, recalculated and synced your reputation, and voilà! (Reputation recalcs have been triggered about 20 times on your account, and about half of these resulted in a change of shown reputation.)

In the future, I'd advise you not to take this reputation thing *too* seriously. If you feel a  reputation discrepancy is persisting for a few days there might be a more serious problem that needs further attention. But not seeing immediate changes is something that happens from time to time, and shouldn't be a cause for great concern. As you see, the system did get there... eventually.

Comment: Thanks, now that it's happened once, and solved itself, I should be fine if it ever happens again.